# "J'aime écouter le rock." ou "J'aime écouter du rock."

Tags: grammaire, articles

Est-ce qu'on dit :

> J'aime écouter le rock.

ou bien :

> J'aime écouter du rock.

Je pensais qu'avec le verbe aimer on devait toujours employer l'article défini, mais j'ai trouvé sur Google des exemples avec l'article partitif...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On dira :

> J'aime le rock

jamais *j'aime *du rock*, mais quand il s'agit d'une habitude, du cas général, on dit  *écouter de la musique* donc :

> J'aime écouter du rock.

Ou peut aussi dire :

> J'aime écouter le rock des années 60.